# Uneven text distribution with two-column layout

Tags: vertical-alignment, templates, two-column

I am comfortable with creating basic LaTeX documents and making minor modifications to templates I can find online, but not much more. The Oxford Bioinformatics journal has an awesome template [here](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/bioinfo01.zip) that I am trying to modify for a school assignment.

The template uses a two-column layout, but if there is not enough text to fill the final page, it distributes the text evenly between the two columns. Is there a way I can modify this template so that the first column is filled before any text flows over to the second column? I've been able to make most of the layout modifications I need in the `bioinfo.cls` file, but I cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `bioinfo` class loads the [`flushend`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flushend) package which (according to the [TeX FAQ](https://tefaq.org/FAQ-balance) in a "somewhat dangerous" way) balances the columns at the end of a two-column document. You should be able to switch off balancing by adding `\raggedend` to your preamble.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use the [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package over the documentclass option for two column layouts. `multicol` does column balancing by default, and overall I feel it works much better than the document class option.

Comment: I'll have to check this package out. I do very little with creating documents from scratch--I usually just adapt templates for my needs. But that sounds like a good place to start.