# Vertical Spacing of twocolumn option

Tags: spacing, two-column

I was wondering how can one place vertical spacing on both the **left** and **right** columns while using the `[twocolumn]` option. I used the `\vspace{}` command above the section of code where the columns begin, but it only puts vertical spacing on the **left** column. I need the **right** column to also be spaced down vertically at the same distance as the **left** column.

Comment: that is only possible on top of a new page. Use package `multicol` instead, if possible.

Comment: I think you're referring to the the `twocolumn` option (to a documentclass), e.g. loaded like this: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`. If I'm mistaken, please revert my edit.

Comment: @Don: Yes, my mistake. Meant to say documentclass and not a package as you stated above. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you could increase the top margin using the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\newgeometry{top=10cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: two column doc with increased top margin]

Notes:

1. options to `geometry`: `pass` tells `geometry` not to change anything, but just load the package. `showframe` makes `geometry` display lines at the margins.
2. `lipsum` is just for blind text (four paragraphs of blind text).
3. This will, as visualized by the lines, also push the header down. Let me know if that's unwanted.

Comment: @ Don: Thanks for the answer. I have to get off now, but I will check with my TeX code tomorrow and see if this does the trick.

Comment: @nightowl: Sure, let me now if you need more help.

Comment: This was good, and what I mean by good is in the sense that this is how I would like it to look so far as the `twocolumn` goes, but I did not want this `lipsum` thing added. Imagine having 50 vocabulary words and you wanted to put 25 words on each column for the page. This is what I was looking for. The left column words 1-25 and the right column 26-50. Is that clear to picture? Let me know if you need more description.

Comment: The `lipsum` is just blind text, simply remove it. If you want the columns balanced, take a look at [TH.'s answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5815). If, however, you want to make a vocab list with one language on the left hand side and the other on the right hand side, I strongly recommend using a table instead of the `twocolumn` option. On tables in general, see e.g. _The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e_. If you want to modify the table further, check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12672.