# \pagebreak and two-column text

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-breaking, two-column

When I use `\pagebreak` in a two-column text, the paragraphs are spread out by vertical spaces only in the current column, so the whole page looks unbalanced (the right column has large spaces between paragraphs, the left column doesn't). Is there a way to make the spaces the same?

Comment: Not with the `twocolum` document class option. You might consider the **multicol** package, instead, that does column balancing. But this requires closing the environment, issuing `\pagebreak` and reopening the environment. May you be more precise about your needs?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the twocolumn class is prescribed by the journal style I am writing for :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\newpage` instead. In my understanding, in two-column mode, the columns are dealt with and typeset like pages. For the difference between `\pagebreak` and `\newpage` see [\pagebreak vs \newpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/736/pagebreak-vs-newpage).

---

Edit: For a balanced layout, use `\usepackage{flushend}`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I need the functionality of `\pagebreak`. `\newpage` does a different thing.

Comment: `\newpage` does about the same as `\pagebreak`, but it doesn't spread the paragraphs of the last column. If you're looking for a balanced layout, you could use `\usepackage{flushend}`, as recommended in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/how-to-balance-last-page-of-two-column-layout-in-latex, or proceed as egreg recommended.