# How do I split the text equally in a twocolumn document?

Tags: two-column

I want the same amount of text in both column. Is there an option for that like there is in the "multicol" package?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities to balance a two-column layout, see [How to balance last page of two-column layout?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/how-to-balance-last-page-of-two-column-layout)

One possibility is the usage of the [balance](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/balance) package:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \balance
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \newpage
    \nobalance
\end{document}
```

Ensure to use `\balance` in a left column. And taken from the manual:

> The \balance command should be given for each page that needs balancing,
> and then turned off at the end of the second column.

So: use `\nobalance` after each balanced column to end the balancing, because otherwise many of the other (full) pages after `\balance` might look ugly at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

use the multicol package, and it has the two behaviors you describe, an example.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols*}

\newpage

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```