# Vertical gap appearing in the second column of a multicolumn environment (oxford bioinformatics template)

Tags: spacing, floats, multicolumn, vertical, gap

I have a problem with a vertical gap appearing in the second column of the second page, instead of text/figure. This problem is not exclusive to the pages near the bibliography because this gap also appeared in another page. Please advise on how I can pull up the text/figure to the top of second column (I'm using the oxford bioinformatics template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-oxford-bioinformatics-journal-new-version/zjrmbrmtrytg).

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\copyrightyear{2015} \pubyear{2015}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\access{Advance Access Publication Date: Day Month Year}
\appnotes{Manuscript Category}

\begin{document}
%\firstpage{1}

\lipsum[90-100]



\begin{figure}[!tpb]%figure1
\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{235pt} \vbox to 100pt{\vfill\hbox to
235pt{\hfill\fontsize{24pt}{24pt}\selectfont FPO\hfill}\vfill}
\end{minipage}}
%\centerline{\includegraphics{fig01.eps}}
\caption{Caption, caption.}\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!tpb]%figure1
\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{235pt} \vbox to 100pt{\vfill\hbox to
235pt{\hfill\fontsize{24pt}{24pt}\selectfont FPO\hfill}\vfill}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{Caption, caption.}\label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!tpb]%figure1
\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{235pt} \vbox to 100pt{\vfill\hbox to
235pt{\hfill\fontsize{24pt}{24pt}\selectfont FPO\hfill}\vfill}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{Caption, caption.}\label{fig:02}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!tpb]%figure1
\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}[t]{235pt} \vbox to 100pt{\vfill\hbox to
235pt{\hfill\fontsize{24pt}{24pt}\selectfont FPO\hfill}\vfill}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{Caption, caption.}\label{fig:03}
\end{figure}

\section*{Acknowledgements}

Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text.  \citealp{Boffelli03} might want to know about  text
text text text\vspace*{-12pt}

\section*{Funding}

This work has been supported by the... Text Text  Text Text.\vspace*{-12pt}

\bibliographystyle{natbib}

%\bibliography{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Bofelli {\it et~al}., 2000]{Boffelli03}
Bofelli,F., Name2, Name3 (2003) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 199}, 133-154.

\bibitem[Bag {\it et~al}., 2001]{Bag01}
Bag,M., Name2, Name3 (2001) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 99}, 33-54.

\bibitem[Yoo \textit{et~al}., 2003]{Yoo03}
Yoo,M.S. \textit{et~al}. (2003) Oxidative stress regulated genes in nigral dopaminergic neurnol cell: correlation with the known pathology in Parkinson's disease. \textit{Brain Res. Mol. Brain Res.}, \textbf{110}(Suppl. 1), 76--84.

\bibitem[Lehmann, 1986]{Leh86}
Lehmann,E.L. (1986) Chapter title. \textit{Book Title}. Vol.~1, 2nd edn. Springer-Verlag, New York.

\bibitem[Crenshaw and Jones, 2003]{Cre03}
Crenshaw, B.,III, and Jones, W.B.,Jr (2003) The future of clinical cancer management: one tumor, one chip. \textit{Bioinformatics}, doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btn000.

\bibitem[Auhtor \textit{et~al}. (2000)]{Aut00}
Auhtor,A.B. \textit{et~al}. (2000) Chapter title. In Smith, A.C. (ed.), \textit{Book Title}, 2nd edn. Publisher, Location, Vol. 1, pp.???--???.

\bibitem[Bardet, 1920]{Bar20}
Bardet, G. (1920) Sur un syndrome d'obesite infantile avec polydactylie et retinite pigmentaire (contribution a l'etude des formes cliniques de l'obesite hypophysaire). PhD Thesis, name of institution, Paris, France.

\bibitem[Bofelli {\it et~al}., 2000]{Boffelli03}
Bofelli,F., Name2, Name3 (2003) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 199}, 133-154.

\bibitem[Bag {\it et~al}., 2001]{Bag01}
Bag,M., Name2, Name3 (2001) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 99}, 33-54.

\bibitem[Yoo \textit{et~al}., 2003]{Yoo03}
Yoo,M.S. \textit{et~al}. (2003) Oxidative stress regulated genes in nigral dopaminergic neurnol cell: correlation with the known pathology in Parkinson's disease. \textit{Brain Res. Mol. Brain Res.}, \textbf{110}(Suppl. 1), 76--84.

\bibitem[Lehmann, 1986]{Leh86}
Lehmann,E.L. (1986) Chapter title. \textit{Book Title}. Vol.~1, 2nd edn. Springer-Verlag, New York.

\bibitem[Crenshaw and Jones, 2003]{Cre03}
Crenshaw, B.,III, and Jones, W.B.,Jr (2003) The future of clinical cancer management: one tumor, one chip. \textit{Bioinformatics}, doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btn000.

\bibitem[Auhtor \textit{et~al}. (2000)]{Aut00}
Auhtor,A.B. \textit{et~al}. (2000) Chapter title. In Smith, A.C. (ed.), \textit{Book Title}, 2nd edn. Publisher, Location, Vol. 1, pp.???--???.

\bibitem[Bardet, 1920]{Bar20}
Bardet, G. (1920) Sur un syndrome d'obesite infantile avec polydactylie et retinite pigmentaire (contribution a l'etude des formes cliniques de l'obesite hypophysaire). PhD Thesis, name of institution, Paris, France.

\bibitem[Bofelli {\it et~al}., 2000]{Boffelli03}
Bofelli,F., Name2, Name3 (2003) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 199}, 133-154.

\bibitem[Bag {\it et~al}., 2001]{Bag01}
Bag,M., Name2, Name3 (2001) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 99}, 33-54.

\bibitem[Yoo \textit{et~al}., 2003]{Yoo03}
Yoo,M.S. \textit{et~al}. (2003) Oxidative stress regulated genes in nigral dopaminergic neurnol cell: correlation with the known pathology in Parkinson's disease. \textit{Brain Res. Mol. Brain Res.}, \textbf{110}(Suppl. 1), 76--84.

\bibitem[Lehmann, 1986]{Leh86}
Lehmann,E.L. (1986) Chapter title. \textit{Book Title}. Vol.~1, 2nd edn. Springer-Verlag, New York.

\bibitem[Crenshaw and Jones, 2003]{Cre03}
Crenshaw, B.,III, and Jones, W.B.,Jr (2003) The future of clinical cancer management: one tumor, one chip. \textit{Bioinformatics}, doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btn000.

\bibitem[Auhtor \textit{et~al}. (2000)]{Aut00}
Auhtor,A.B. \textit{et~al}. (2000) Chapter title. In Smith, A.C. (ed.), \textit{Book Title}, 2nd edn. Publisher, Location, Vol. 1, pp.???--???.

\bibitem[Bardet, 1920]{Bar20}
Bardet, G. (1920) Sur un syndrome d'obesite infantile avec polydactylie et retinite pigmentaire (contribution a l'etude des formes cliniques de l'obesite hypophysaire). PhD Thesis, name of institution, Paris, France.

\bibitem[Bofelli {\it et~al}., 2000]{Boffelli03}
Bofelli,F., Name2, Name3 (2003) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 199}, 133-154.

\bibitem[Bag {\it et~al}., 2001]{Bag01}
Bag,M., Name2, Name3 (2001) Article title, {\it Journal Name}, {\bf 99}, 33-54.

\bibitem[Yoo \textit{et~al}., 2003]{Yoo03}
Yoo,M.S. \textit{et~al}. (2003) Oxidative stress regulated genes in nigral dopaminergic neurnol cell: correlation with the known pathology in Parkinson's disease. \textit{Brain Res. Mol. Brain Res.}, \textbf{110}(Suppl. 1), 76--84.

\bibitem[Lehmann, 1986]{Leh86}
Lehmann,E.L. (1986) Chapter title. \textit{Book Title}. Vol.~1, 2nd edn. Springer-Verlag, New York.

\bibitem[Crenshaw and Jones, 2003]{Cre03}
Crenshaw, B.,III, and Jones, W.B.,Jr (2003) The future of clinical cancer management: one tumor, one chip. \textit{Bioinformatics}, doi:10.1093/bioinformatics/btn000.

\bibitem[Auhtor \textit{et~al}. (2000)]{Aut00}
Auhtor,A.B. \textit{et~al}. (2000) Chapter title. In Smith, A.C. (ed.), \textit{Book Title}, 2nd edn. Publisher, Location, Vol. 1, pp.???--???.

\bibitem[Bardet, 1920]{Bar20}
Bardet, G. (1920) Sur un syndrome d'obesite infantile avec polydactylie et retinite pigmentaire (contribution a l'etude des formes cliniques de l'obesite hypophysaire). PhD Thesis, name of institution, Paris, France.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: first page]

[image: second page where gap appears]

[image: bibliography]

Comment: Can you maybe add a link to the template as it doesn't seem to be a standard class available on ctan. Also, I would recommend replacing the gif of your document with a single page that illustrates your issue, as the changing pages make it more or less impossible, to see anything. And you might want to check out the `lipsum` package for blind text, which will help you make your MWE a bit more minimal. This helps to highlight the actual issue without having to repeat the word `text` so often.

Comment: When I run your document (but replacing the figures that I don't have) I don't see this effect. So maybe it is something in your `sf4e_5.tex` that is causing this.

Comment: There is also that `picture(0,0)(35,0)...` text in the four corners where there should be crop marks. So there is something fishy in your document.

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5439/113546), in that case it may help to put `\raggedend` after `\begin{document}`. I can't reconstruct your problem, so I can't check if this works.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @CarLaTeX thanks. On a different note, after editing my post I can no longer see the images I uploaded. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: @MarkusG. I've replaced the text with lipsum, thanks. I've also split the pages into single pages but I can't seem to see them.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I've replaced the figures with boxes, and the vertical gap is still present. I've tried \raggedend, it doesn't work.

Comment: @maia I tried to retrieve them from the edit history, please check if they are correct.

Comment: I ran your new document, both on my local TeX system on my laptop and on Overleaf, and it comes out normal. The references just continue in the second column.

Comment: And in your output there are still the texts "picture(0,0)..." in the corners, which means something is broken in your LaTeX installation.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum, thanks :). the original overleaf project was cluttered with files. I reconstructed the project but only containing pertinent files and now it works (even the "picture(0,0)..." in the corners disappeared). I guess some of the file/s in the old cluttered project messed up with the main latex document. Or I was using an old version of the bioinfo template.

Comment: @CarLaTeX i think it works now. thanks :)

Comment: @maia You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

the original overleaf project was cluttered with files. I reconstructed the project but only containing pertinent files and now it works (even the "picture(0,0)..." in the corners disappeared). I guess some of the file/s in the old cluttered project messed up with the main latex document. Or I was using an old version of the bioinfo template.